# How to open sqlite in sqlite prompt

Tags: sqlite

I can open sqlite db in shell prompt:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

When i input  sqlite3 to enter sqlite environment,how can i open test.db in sqlite prompt?

It is no use to input

```
~$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> sqlite3 test.db
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`sqlite3`](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) tools always opens the database file that is given as parameter. If there is no file name, it will open a temporary database with a random name.

It is not possible to change the database afterwards.